# how to retrieve image from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am saving some data in SQLite data for android. I want to show or retrieve the image data. following is the code I am trying. please help me out:

---retrieving image but I cant do it
public String getData() {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_NUMBER };

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);

    int iname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    // int iphoto = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHOTO);

    int inumber = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NUMBER);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iname) + " " + c.getString(inumber) + "\n";

    }

    return result;
}
```

----this method is saving data in SQLite database:
    public long create_Entry(ContactInfo objContact) {

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(KEY_NAME, objContact.getFname());

    cv.put(KEY_NUMBER, objContact.getPhoneNo());

    cv.put(KEY_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(objContact.getBitmap()));

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting into database, you need to convert your Bitmap image into byte array first then apply it using database query.
 When retrieving from database, you certainly have a byte array of image, what you need to do is to convert byte array back to original image.

**Code snippet** -

```
 // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
```

Comment: I already have this in my code. But I am having error in retrieving the image from SQLite database.

Comment: You need to get the image in `Byte array` byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);